# Can I redirect all output to /dev/null from within python?

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python script that'll fork a child process. The parent process should be able to write stuff like `Started child at xxxxx`, but the child process output should be redirected to `/dev/null`. How can I do that from within python?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import sys
old_stdout, old_stderr = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
sys.stdout = open('/dev/null', 'w')
sys.stderr = open('/dev/null', 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a cross-platform way to redirect the output to the `null file`, then we can use `os.devnull` attribute to specify that we want to output to be redirected to the `null file`.

```
import sys
import os

stderr = sys.stderr
stdout = sys.stdout

# print(os.devnull)

print("Hell o World!")

sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')

print("This is redirected to null")
```

Output:

```
Hell o World!
```

First, we are creating a backup for the default `standard output` and `standard error`:

```
stderr = sys.stderr
stdout = sys.stdout
```

Then we display msg to the default `standard output`:

```
print("Hell o World!")
```

Next, we are redirecting the output messages and the error messages to the `null file`:

```
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
```

Here we are verifying that the output is redirected to the `null file`:

```
print("This is redirected to null")
```

If in case, you want to find where the `null file` is located it may return different results because this depends on the *operating system* on which the Python program is running:

```
print(os.devnull)
```

It is also possible that you want to **reset** where output and error messages are displayed to the *default* `standard output` and `standard error` in that case you can use this approach:

```
import sys
import os

stderr = sys.stderr
stdout = sys.stdout

sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')

print("This is redirected to null.")

sys.stderr = stderr
sys.stdout = stdout

print("This is redirected to the standard output.")
```

Output:

```
This is redirected to the standard output.
```